# Vue.js Input field loses its focus after entry of one character

Tags: javascript, focus, vue.js

I have a view with an input field, which can be multiplicated by a given button. The problem is that after any entry of a char, the focus of the input field is lost. You have to click again to enter another char.

Do someone have a clue what could be the problem?

My model:

```
'model': [
    ...,
    'filter': [
        ...,
        'something': [
            'string'
        ]
    ]
]
```

My code:

```
<div v-for="(something, index) in model.filter.something" v-bind:key="something">
    <input type="text" v-model.trim="model.filter.something[index]"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you include is complicated. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RoyJ Done, thank you for your first feedback

Comment: You show `something` as being an array, but also refer to `model.something.inOrExclude` and also have `model.filter.something` which appears to be an array. Are all the `something`s related?

Comment: They are, but not directly and I think not as part of this problem. However I noticed, that I can minimize the code a little bit more.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a changing value as `key`. Vue expects `key` to indicate a unique identifier for the item. When you change it, it becomes a new item and must be re-rendered.

In the snippet below, I have two loops, both using the same data source. The first is keyed the way you have it set up. The second uses `index` instead (that may not be what you need, but the point is to use something other than what you're editing; in this example, `key` isn't needed anyway). The first exhibits the loss-of-focus you describe, the second works as expected.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'model': {
      'filter': {
        'something': [
          'string'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(something, index) in model.filter.something" v-bind:key="something">
    <input type="text" v-model.trim="model.filter.something[index]" />
    {{something}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="(something, index) in model.filter.something">
    <input type="text" v-model.trim="model.filter.something[index]" :key="index" />
    {{something}}
  </div>
</div>
```