# BootstrapVue: b-form-input losing focus after each input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of b-form-input in one of your applications. Each time I do a keystroke in one of the inputs the field loses the focus. This happens not just for one input but for all inputs in the application.

There are no watchers or computed properties connected to the data that is binded to the inputs and the inputs have no event handler.

We have an older version of this application running on another server without any problems. I checked the differences in git but only some small changes were made in the backend without relation to the inputs.

input code:

```
<b-form-input v-model="data.item.name" :state="nameState(data.item.name)" size="sm"></b-form-input>
<b-form-invalid-feedback>Name hast to be filled</b-form-invalid-feedback>
```

nameState code:

```
nameState(name) {
   return (name !== null && name !== '') ? null : false
}
```

We are using vue version 2.5.17 and bootstrap-vue 2.0.0-rc.11 but i already tried bootstrap-vue 2.0.0-rc.13 with the same result.

Any ideas what could cause this behaviour? I have never seen something like that in our other applications using the same frameworks and versions.

If you need further details just tell me.

Regards
Najo

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074144/vue-js-input-field-loses-its-focus-after-entry-of-one-character