# Strange Behavior Of Embedded Video & v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I was creating a video popup/overlay for a project where the video could be viewed in a large player or a small player and ran into this very strange behavior.  When the video is large I wanted the title and description to show and when small the same to be hidden. So I simply added a `v-if` directive to the title and description and toggled those based on if the video was being shown in the large state or not.

The strange behavior is that while playing the embedded video iframe is forced to reload when the video size is changed, **but only when** the iframe is preceded and followed directly by the title and description with `v-if` directives.  If you change this arrangement at all, whether by moving one element to another location, or surrounding one by a div, the behavior stops.

Anyone have a clue as to why this behavior occurs or is it a bug?

I reproduced the behavior in the jfiddle links below:

https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/3w8cujvp/2/  (not working correctly)

https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/uj97oh0k/1/  (working as expected)

Script:

```
  data:{
    vidLarge: true,
    vidWidth: window.innerWidth * .45,
    vidHeight: (window.innerWidth * .45 * 9) / 16,
  },
  methods:{
    toggleLarge(){
         this.vidLarge = !this.vidLarge;
       this.vidWidth = this.vidLarge ? window.innerWidth * .45 : 150;
       this.vidHeight = (this.vidWidth * 9) /16;
    }
   },
```

Template: (with strange behavior)

```
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h3 v-if="vidLarge">Video 1</h3>
      <iframe :width="vidWidth" :height="vidHeight" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VqKjr4I4Fdo"></iframe>
      <p v-if="vidLarge">A Vue Tutorial</p>
    </div>  
    <button @click="toggleLarge">Toggle Size </button>
  </div>
```

Template: (works correctly)

```
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h3 v-if="vidLarge">Video 1</h3>
      <p v-if="vidLarge">A Vue Tutorial</p> <!-- moved above iframe -->
      <iframe :width="vidWidth" :height="vidHeight" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VqKjr4I4Fdo"></iframe>

    </div>  
    <button @click="toggleLarge">Toggle Size </button>
  </div>

   or.....

  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h3 v-if="vidLarge">Video 1</h3>
      <iframe :width="vidWidth" :height="vidHeight" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VqKjr4I4Fdo"></iframe>
      <div> <!-- separate from iframe with another element -->
        <p v-if="vidLarge">A Vue Tutorial</p>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <button @click="toggleLarge">Toggle Size </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can create vue snippet on Stack Overflow as well. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43095557/3082296) (Also: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992))

Comment: @adiga  Thanks I am aware of this.  I like jfiddle better.